# How to debug CircleCI VM via SSH?

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm trying to remote debug a CircleCI virtual machine through SSH, using their "Rebuild with SSH" option. When I do so, it prints the following message:

```
You can now SSH into this VM if your SSH public key is added:
    $ ssh -p [port] ubuntu@[IP address]
Use the same SSH public key that you use for GitHub.  If you have not added your public keys to this build and you would like to SSH to it, you can add them by clicking the "SSH to this build" button in the "Debug via SSH" tab.
```

Unfortunately, there appears to be no "SSH to this build" button anywhere on the page, so I'm forced to do this otherwise.

How do I get this SSH key? How do I add it to the build? Once I do, what then? Do they refer to my personal SSH public key on GitHub, or that of the organization I'm part of?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to copy & paste the SSH command that the CircleCI Dashboard gives you at the top of that build's page.

This would be copy & pasted into a terminal on Linux or OS X machines, using Putty on Windows machines, or Bash on Windows in Windows 10.

The SSH key that is used is pulled directly from GitHub. If you can already push to the GitHub repo from your local computer, then you're good to go. That same key will be used for the CircleCI container. Just run the SSH command and you're in.

-Ricardo
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: how do you cancel the SSH debug without having to wait for 30 minutes?

Comment: You can cancel the build right from the build page on the website. They'll be a button/link near the top.